# Let $f\in L_2(\mathbb R)$ be a function. Is $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|f(k)|^2<\infty $?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f\in L_2(\mathbb R)$ be a function. Is $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|f(k)|^2<\infty $ ?

I am trying to prove the relation $\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|f(k)|^2<\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^2dx$.

I am not able to produce examples to say above relation is false, so I guess that the above relation is true. But, I am not able to prove that.

Please help me!

Comment: For a counter-example, take a function that is almost everywhere $0$...

Comment: You cannot expect it to be true, since the LHS only makes reference to $f$ on a null set.

Comment: nope nada null zip

Comment: If we assume $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, then Is my result true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is false. Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ via $ f(x) = x \chi_\mathbb{Z}(x) $, where $ \chi_\mathbb{Z}$ is the characteristic function of the integers. Then $ f $ is zero almost everywhere, so $ f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}) $. However, $ \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} |f(k)|^2 = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} k^2 $, which is certainly not finite.

Comment: ok. Will it be true if we assume $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$?

Comment: You can still find counterexamples. In fact, I'm confident there are smooth counterexamples, but I can't think of an explicit one. For a continuous counterexample, consider the triangle function which is 0 everywhere except an interval. On that interval it rises linearly to a peak then decreases back to 0. Then let f be the sum of triangle functions with intervals around the integers. If you pick the heights and widths of these triangles appropriately, you will come up with a counterexample. This sort of counterexample is nice when you want continuity. You can try and modify it to be smooth.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.